# NPM: download the same library many times in different versions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, jspm

I'm working on Play Framework 2.4 and AngularJs 1.5.8 with coffeescript.
I am analyzing if it is convenient to use npm.
We are using several libraries and many of them have their own dependencies.
So, I do not know, what would happen if 2 different libraries had the same dependency but in different versions?
Could it origin a problem? Which version will be downloaded in the node_modules directory?
Is it possible to use 2 versions of the same library just using npm or do I need something like jspm?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: NPM is designed for multiple different depenancy's,..  It just doesn't flatten them.

Answer (score 3):

NPM, from the start was always designed to cope with multiple versions of a dependency.  It did this by making all NPM module have there own node_modules directory,.  This did cause module bloat, so NPM was later made to intelligently flatten the node_modules directory were it could.

But for now let's forget about NPM and node_module directory flattening and think about how it was possible to have 2 versions of the same dependency.

Let's say we have 2 modules called `X` and `Y`, both required a module called `Z`,  problem is `X` required version 1, and `Y` required version 2.  NPM would create a structure like ->

```
node_modules
  X  
    nodule_modules
      Z ver 1
  Y  
    nodule_modules
      Z ver 2
```

Because of the way node searches node_modules directory, X would always find the correct version of Z.  And the same for Y.  This is because node will first check the current directory for a node_modules, if this does not exists it traverses up the directory tree until it finds a module called Z.

Now back to the flattening bit.

If X & Y both were now using Z ver 2.  The directory structure would look something like.

```
node_modules
  X
  Y
  Z ver 2
```

As you can see,  X will now find Z ver 2, and so will Y.
This is a brief explanation of how Node does module resolution.

Hope that helps..

ps. And like @sripberger has pointed out, knowing what to keep and merge is determined by semantic versioning.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!This is very helpful for me. Do you know if it is possible to indicate to  node that I want be who decides wich version of my depedendency I want to conserved in this cases? In your example, I would like to decide wich version of Z I want to conserve, and that node only notice me that an error has been ocurred.

Comment: It's possible to ignore semver if that's what you mean, basically don't allow NPM to decide,..   And just copy the node_modules and versions you want..  The way I do this is create a temporary directory,  NPM install the version I want into this directory, and then just copy the module into your current node_modules directory.  Basically ignoring any semver,  you would basically never use NPM in this directory you install these into.. IOW: your manually controlling dependencies.

Comment: Yes! This is that I want.So, I will use npm in my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

npm uses [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) to specify version ranges. By default, when you run `npm install --save foo`, it downloads the latest version of the `foo` package and stores its number in `package.json` dependencies, beginning with a caret (^). The caret indicates 'compatible' with, which generally means anything with the same major version (the first number).

When npm resolves nested dependencies, it checks to see if the version strings of dependencies can be resolved with a single version. If so, it installs that version in the top-level `node_modules` directory. Otherwise, it installs a version for each in nested `node_modules` directories.

In other words, it handles this problem automatically, provided publishers follow the semantic versioning conventions and don't include breaking changes in minor or bugfix releases. This is enforced by community, in that failure to follow said conventions is a good way to make people not want to use your stuff.

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience, NPM normally replaces the latest version of a package with the old one. So I think if you are using NPM then it is not possible to store 2 different versions of the same package.

Comment: NPM will only replace the depancy if it can satisfy the semver.  And it's totally possible to have 2 versions of the NPM module running.  IOW: Most semver's are only upgradable inside the same major version.

Comment: Thanks Keith! So, what about the node_modules directory? When I open it, will there be 2 folders with the same name or npm renames them? Thank you!

Comment: @JohanaAnez  I'll post a brief explanation.